# <Terminated> message in eclipse console?

Tags: java, eclipse

I run my project but get this message.

"terminated Payroll [Java Application] /Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java"

Im extremely new to eclipse and java in general. I don't know what to download or do. Please help.

java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Employee {

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

private String firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
private String lastName = keyboard.nextLine();
private double hourlyPayRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
private double hoursWorked = keyboard.nextDouble();
private static final double FEDERAL_TAX_RATE = 18.0;
private static final double PROVINCIAL_TAX_RATE = 4.5;
private static final double EMPLOYMENT_INSURANCE = 22.35;
private static final double UNION_DUES = 7.85;



public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    System.out.println("Enter the employee's name (first then last): " + keyboard.next()); 
    firstName = keyboard.next(); 
}// setFirstName

public void setLastName(String lastName) {

    lastName = keyboard.next(); 
}// setLastName

public void setHourlyPayRate(double hourlyPayRate) {
    System.out.println("Enter " + firstName + lastName + "'s hourly pay rate: " );
}// SetHourlyPayRate

private String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}// firstName

private String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}// lastName

private double getHourlyPayRate() {
    return hourlyPayRate;
}// hourlyPayRate

private double getHoursWorked() {
    return hoursWorked;
}// hoursWorked

public double calculateGrossPay(){
    return hourlyPayRate * hoursWorked; 
}

public double calculateFederalTax() {
    return calculateGrossPay() * FEDERAL_TAX_RATE;
}// FEDERAL_TAX_RATE()

public double calculateProvincialTax() {
    return calculateGrossPay() * PROVINCIAL_TAX_RATE;
}// PROVINCIAL_TAX_RATE

public double getEmploymentInsurance() {
    return calculateGrossPay() * EMPLOYMENT_INSURANCE;
}// EMPLOYMENT_INSURANCE

public double getUnionDues() {
    return calculateGrossPay() * UNION_DUES;
}// UNION_DUES

public double calculateNetPay(){
    return calculateGrossPay() - calculateGrossPay() +getUnionDues() + getEmploymentInsurance() +    calculateProvincialTax() + calculateFederalTax(); 
}

public void setHoursWorked(double hoursWorked) {

}// setHoursWorked

}// Employee()
```

the main() is this

```
/**
 * 
*/
package employee;

/**
* @author Nico
*
*/
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Payroll {
Employee employee = new Employee();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    System.out.print("Enter the employee's name (first then last):\n");
    System.out.print("Enter Elly Funt's hourly pay rate: \n" );
    System.out.print("Enter the number of hours Elly Funt worked this rate: \n" );
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("Employee Pay Summary: \n");
    System.out.print("Employee Name: \n");
    System.out.print("Hourly rate: \n");
    System.out.print("Hours worked: \n");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("Gross Pay: \n");
    System.out.print("Dedcutions: \n");
    System.out.print("\tFederal tax: \n");
    System.out.print("\tProvincial tax: \n");
    System.out.print("\tEmployment Insurance: \n");
    System.out.print("\tUnion Dues: \n");
    System.out.print("Net Pay: \n");
}//Main()


}//Payroll
```

Answer (score 2):

It means your program is terminated, the main method has finished.

Comment: How do i make it show the System.out.print ?? nothing is showing up.

Comment: I added my code, im not sure if its right but i should be getting a system.out.print

Comment: @NicolasBeaulieu The code of the `main` method would help

Comment: you don't have a main method. Only the content of it can be displayed

Comment: No main method means your program cannot run any instructions.

Comment: I have a main method in another class. My assignment says to make 2 classes. One with a main method and one without.

Comment: So run the class containing the main method. It looks like you have run the other one.